# Mapping table SQL autoincremented column or not

Tags: mysql, sql

When creating a mapping table I've seen people not use primary keys and others use them. What advantages does having it vs not having it provide.

Keep in mind I'm thinking of a simple mapping table where it has two numeric values that map back to a surrogate key in another table.

Example

```
Cars
id - 1
name - Honda

Car_Parts
id - 3
name - Hood

Cars_Parts_Mapping
cars_id - 1
car_parts - 3
```

Comment: Always use a primary key. In this case, your primary key is `(cars_id,car_parts)`. The best of both worlds: and primary key, and no extra column. However, the reason a lot of people create an _extra_ column with an auto-incrementing integer primary key, is because they are to lazy to build an _interface_ that manipulates rows based on _2_ fields rather then one.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that "primary key" is the same thing as "an autoincrent integer column" - well it is not. Wrikken is right: in your case `(cars_id, car_parts)` *is* a perfect primary key.

Comment: Sorry meant to say auto incremented id

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a valid question that I cannot seem to find a reasonable answer to.

Answer (score 3):

*(upgraded comment to answer)*

Always use a primary key. In this case, your primary key is `(cars_id,car_parts)`. The best of both worlds: and primary key, and no extra column. However, the reason a lot of people create an extra column with an auto-incrementing integer primary key, is because they are to lazy to build an interface that manipulates rows based on 2 fields rather then one.

Needing a `PRIMARY KEY` is especially true for `InnoDB` tables: if you don't define one, the engine will just [create a hidden one for you](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html):

> If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL locates the first UNIQUE index where all the key columns are NOT NULL and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.
>
> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB internally generates a hidden clustered index on a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion order.

It is not uncommon to define a second index on those kinds of tables to be able to *also* quickly search on `car_parts` (now it only responds well to searches on `car_id`), by creating a reverse index as well: `INDEX(car_parts,car_id)`. It means a small performance hit in `INSERT`'s, but if you `SELECT` more then you manipulate data (which is usually the case), this is justified by the quicker `SELECT`'s.

Comment: That makes sense. I was not aware that innodb adds a primary key for you behind the scenes. Then it makes no sense not to have a primary key on a mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use primary keys whenever possible. They're usually the fastest to `JOIN` against and are guaranteed to be unique.

Linking to something other than the primary key should be done as a last resort.